# don't know how to fix cross-browser problems

Tags: testing, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

Can anyone help me fix some cross-browser issues?  My website address is http://s423839726.onlinehome.us/index2.html.  It looks fine in firefox 13, but in IE9 the "contact" button is all wonky.

Also, where does one learn how to fix cross-browser inconsistencies?

Comment: Also, I've noticed in several other browsers, my social links are on top of the logo, not positioned to the left where I would like them.  Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is very vague.  You should isolate specific examples of code that behaves differently and ask about those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the inconsistency can also be seen in Opera. Your problem is the UL element. It hangs at that position on the right as it has display "inline" set and contains a stray A element. This combination moves your contact menu element a bit down. You should try to clean up the markup as it contains nested elements (mainly A elements) that are not strictly necessary. Another problem is, that you are mixing left and right floating. Additionally you are mixing left and right paddings and marging which may lead to different behaviour in browsers, makes calculating harder and can lead to collapsing margins problems. I'd advise you to try a more semantic markup for your menu like:

```html
<ul id="topnav">
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

and with this simple markup you are able to style your menu. If you reach a point, where adjusting dimensions, paddings and margins of elements are not enough to style things the way you want, you may begin to introduce non-semantic elements (e.g. SPAN elements) within LI or A elements to have some more means to shift things around via CSS.

A simple approach to get your navigation styled is the following: Float each LI to the left and use only left margins/paddings to create visual space.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 60px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

ul a {
    padding-right: 32px;
    padding-left: 32px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #ccc;
}

ul a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Something like that. Left border still missing. Your whole menu block (the UL) should be positioned to the right using left padding or right floating or whatever. Prefix the selectors with #topnav if you want to mitigate changing UL and LI styles elsewhere on your page. This is just a simple illustration that you do not need much markup or styles to have a horizontal menu like the one you want. Start simple and search for tutorials on horizontal menus using UL/LIs. There are plenty out there. Good luck.